# How can I format the value when adding it to a DataGridView column?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a line of code that puts a value into a DataGridView column:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[2].Value = MBRHISTDETLDt.Rows[r].ItemArray[0];
```

The value going in is a text field that looks like this:

```
"00001100914401"
```

I'd like to format it so that it looks like the following when adding it to the column:

```
"110-09-144.01"
```

Basically, I'd like to trim all leading zeros and have the remaining number in the format ###-##-##.##.

I think I can use the TrimStart() method of the String class to remove the leading zeros, but I'm not sure about an easy way to format the rest of the string without substringing it and inserting the dashes and period.  I'm hoping there's an easier way.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String value = MBRHISTDETLDt.Rows[r].ItemArray[0].ToString(); 
value  = Regex.Replace(value.TrimStart('0'), @"^(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d*)$", "$1-$2-$3.$4");
dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[2].Value = value;
```

Comment: Well, that kinda worked.  It trimmed the leading zeros, but did not format the string.  So instead of "110-09-144.01" I got "1100914401".  But, still this is a start.  I'll tinker with it and see what happens.  I haven't used regular expressions before so this will be a good start.  Thank you!

Comment: This worked great.  First time I tried it, I made a typo and it only trimmed the leading zeros and nothing else.  I re-examined your code, saw my error and fixed it, and tried again.  It worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!